# Make properties of a class parameters to a function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, reflection

My intention is to pass public properties of a class, like say:

```
class MyTestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime  StartedAt { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
}
```

to a function a parameters:

```
static void MyCustomFunc(params Expression<Func<MyTestClass, object>>[] props)
{
    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        // The following only works for Name property, not for StartedAt or Duration
        MemberExpression member = p.Body as MemberExpression;
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;

        string name = propertyInfo.Name;
        Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        Func<MyTestClass, object> func = p.Compile();
    }
}
```

The function is supposed to gather this info and feed it into an exporter class that exports sets of `MyTestClass` objects to a CSV file.

The output written to the CSV file is dependent on the number, type and order of properties fed into `MyCustomFunc`.

So this:

```
MyCustomFunc(x => x.Name, x => x.StartedAt);
```

produces a different result from:

```
MyCustomFunc(x => x.StartedAt, x => x.Name);
```

and

```
MyCustomFunc(x => x.StartedAt, x => x.Name, x => x.Duration);
```

is different from

```
MyCustomFunc(x => x.Duration, x => x.StartedAt, x => x.Name);
```

My problem is making the reflection work. For some reason I fail to comprehend `p.Body`:

- for `{x => x.Name}` is equal to `{x.Name}` but
- for `{x => x.StartedAt}` is equal to `{Convert(x.StartedAt)}`

The first one can be handled by

```
MemberExpression member = p.Body as MemberExpression;
```

but the second one returns `null`, so I get a null reference exception.

Comment: `Expression<Func<MyTestClass, object>>`: The lambdas you're passing return `object`. DateTime is a struct, so it has to be boxed to make it an object. That'll happen with any value type. I'd just add a special case for value types and move on.

Comment: Do you even need to use `Expression`s at all? Though `MemberExpression member = p.Body as MemberExpression ?? (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)p.Body).Operand;` will get around this for now.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Now that we have `nameof` in C#, my suggestion would be to just use compile-time strings (and pass them with `nameof(x.Duration)`) instead of all that run-time expression magic. See also: [Expression vs nameof](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38324208/87698).

Comment: When you say that you want to pass properties as parameters, what does that mean? When a method receives a property as a parameter, what will it do with it - read it? You might want `Func<T, string[]>` which takes an object like `MyTestClass` and returns the strings to write to the CSV file.

Comment: @ScottHannen @Heinzi You can see from the code - when he passes `x => x.Name`, then he's using that *both* to get the name of the property (`"Name"`), and also to get its value at the same time.

Comment: As @EdPlunkett says, `DateTime` is a struct, you can achieve what you want doing `member = p.Body as MemberExpression ?? ((UnaryExpression)p.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;` instead.

Comment: `if (p.Body is UnaryExpression ue && ue.Operand is MemberExpression ueMember)
                {
                    propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)ueMember.Member;
                } else if (p.Body is MemberExpression member) {...} else { /*throw*/ }` is how I'd do it. Same difference.

Comment: `var body = p.Body; if (body is UnaryExpression ua) { body = ua.Operand; }; var member = body as MemberExpression; if (member == null) { throw ... } member.Member.Name;` would be my approach...

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's exactly what I needed, thank you! You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The business of hard-coding a type parameter made me itch a little bit, so I changed that. I had a feeling you were going to be messing with that part next. Let me know if that's not the case and I'll change it back.

```
public static void MyCustomFunc<T>(this T inst, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] props)
{
    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = null;

        //  Because the return type of the lambda is object, when the property is a value 
        //  type, the Expression will have to be a unary expression to box the value. 
        //  The MemberExpression will be the operand from that UnaryExpression. 
        if (p.Body is UnaryExpression ue && ue.Operand is MemberExpression ueMember)
        {
            propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)ueMember.Member;
        }
        else if (p.Body is MemberExpression member)
        {
            propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)member.Member;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameters must be property access expressions " 
                + "in the form x => x.Property");
        }

        string name = propertyInfo.Name;
        Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
        Func<T, object> func = p.Compile();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new MyTestClass { Name = "Stan", StartedAt = DateTime.Now }
    .MyCustomFunc(x => x.Name, x => x.StartedAt);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, to pass in a class Poperties as expressions and obtain their PropertyInfo through reflection. Thanks again!